# WinSCP Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles does not work with mask with time constraint

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to get the files from the SFTP server. The goal is, to get files newer than 24 hours.

This mask works. The count returns 9018.

```
var filesCount1 =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        serverPath, "*.xml", WinSCP.EnumerationOptions.None).Count();
```

This mask does not work. The count returns 0.

```
var filesCount2 =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        serverPath, "*.xml>24HS", WinSCP.EnumerationOptions.None).Count();
```

How can I fix it? I want to get file one by one, because I need to do some validation before the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` supports simple Windows wildcards only:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles#parameters

---

But you can simply filter the enumeration that the method returns:

```
DateTime limit = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var filesCount1 = 
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        serverPath, "*.xml", WinSCP.EnumerationOptions.None)
    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime > limit)
    .Count();
```

---

*Note that this counts "files newer than 24 hours", as you asked for. What is not what file mask `>24HS` means. So I'm not sure what exactly are you after.*

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that I replied :D Thanks for for your answer, I hadn't noticed what was written in small print in the documentation before. I used simple converter and the filter which you suggested.